# how to send certain parameters encoded in soap - xml rpc request in jmeter

Tags: soap, jmeter

I am using SOAP/XML-RPC request in jmeter. I have 2 questions

1. If we have a rest endpoint with same url which can serve both GET and POST based on the HTTP method that is sent , how to send GET call using SOAP/XML-RPC request because it inherently sending only POST
2. In the SOAP/XML-RPC Data I am sending like this

   **clientid=${clientid}&&instanceid=${instanceid}**

   and I want to send encoded data for ${instanceid}. How can I do it using the above sampler
   I know how to implement the above 2 things using HTTP Request sampler. But my requirement is specifically to use SOAP/XML-RPC sampler
   Any Help in this regard is greatly appreciated !!!
   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) sampler can send only HTTP POST requests by design. See [SoapSampler.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/SoapSampler.java) code for reference.

If you need to encode your parameters somehow you can use:

- [__urlencode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function - to encode parameters as  application/x-www-form-urlencoded string
- [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) - for any other encoding supported (Base64, MD5, etc.)

If you need to send HTTP GET request you have to either use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler in combination with [HTTP Header Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send "Content-Type" header with the value of "text/xml" or develop your own sampler on top of the SoapSampler.

Comment: This specifically answers my question. The code I used in BeanShell Preprocessor is: log.info("Inside Preprocessor");
import java.net.URLEncoder;
encode_string = vars.get("tickcount");
log.info("Before Encoding...:"+encode_string);
encoded_string = URLEncoder.encode(encode_string,"UTF-8");
log.info("After Encoding:"+encoded_string);
vars.put("tickcount",encoded_string);